# Instance variables and local variables confusion

Tags: vb.net

Please take a look at sample1 below:

```
Public Class LocalVariable

    Public Sub Run()
        Dim TestVariable As Integer
        TestVariable = Method1(TestVariable)
        TestVariable = Method2(TestVariable)
        TestVariable = Method3(TestVariable)
    End Sub

    Private Function Method1(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
        Return x + 1
    End Function

    Private Function Method2(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
        Return x + 2
    End Function

    Private Function Method3(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
        Return x + 3
    End Function

End Class
```

and sample 2 below:

```
Public Class InstanceVariable

    Dim TestVariable As Integer

    Public Sub Run()
        Method1()
        Method2()
        Method3()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method1()
        TestVariable = TestVariable + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method2()
        TestVariable = TestVariable + 2
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method3()
        TestVariable = TestVariable + 3
    End Sub

End Class
```

The outcome is obviously the same after each program runs i.e. TestVariable=6.  Every example I find online and at work uses sample 1.  Surely this is a misuse of instance variable as TestVariable should be shared across functions? Therefore an instance variable should be used.

Comment: Just so we're clear: sample 1 has a local variable. It is local to a specific function. Sample 2 has an instance variable, because it is scoped to a specific instance of a type. I think perhaps your terminology is backwards. At no point in sample 1 is TestVariable ever "shared across functions". As a value type, a copy is made for each function call. Even if it were passed ByRef, because of structured programming rules it's only in one method at a time: one returns before the next is called.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, thanks.  I have edited the question to try to make it more clearer.  Does it make sense?

Comment: Remove the for loops. They distract from what you're doing, and make your conjecture that the result will be 6 just plain wrong in both samples. Have your main method just call Method's 1-3 in turn once. Also, to wander is to go drifting around. To wonder is to be curious about something.

Comment: Also, the paragraph immediately following sample 2 makes little sense, because you keep saying instance variable where it seems like you meant local.

Comment: Thanks.  I have amended the offending paragraph again.  I am trying to argue that sample 2 should be used.

Comment: `TestVariable =0` needs to be issued somewhere to initialize the field and/or the local var.

Answer (score 4):

**The two samples don't mean the same thing.**

The difference is what happens if you call Run() more than once over the life of the program. The Run() method in sample 2 never resets TestVariable, so it will continue to get larger and larger. In sample 1, the result will always be 6 because TestVariable is a new variable with each call to the function. Which is more correct depends *entirely* on what you're trying to do.

**There is a third option**

All else being equal, I also recommend the sample 1 approach from those two options. However, instance vs local variable is not the distinction. There's no reason sample 1 couldn't also use an instance variable with those method definitions. So our third option would look like this:

```
Public Class InstanceVariableWithSampleOneFunctions

    Dim TestVariable As Integer

    Public Sub Run()
        TestVariable = Method1(TestVariable)
        TestVariable = Method2(TestVariable)
        TestVariable = Method3(TestVariable)
    End Sub

    Private Function Method1(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
        Return x + 1
    End Function

    Private Function Method2(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
        Return x + 2
    End Function

    Private Function Method3(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
        Return x + 3
    End Function
End Class
```

This uses the instance variable from sample 2 with the methods from sample 1. I'll call it sample 3.

This cuts better to the heart of your question, because now sample 3 has the same behavior as sample 2. Whether you should choose 1 or 2 depends on which behavior you need. But whether you should choose 2 or 3 depends on the merits of the coding style. Both 2 and 3 rely on an instance variable in the Run() method, but 2 also uses an instance variable in the additional methods, while 3 uses a local variable.

I can say that at this point, comparing 2 and 3, I definitely prefer sample 3. The methods from sample 3 have more of a functional style: accept an input, return an output. This gives them a higher level of abstraction, which makes it easier to refactor sample 3 to do things like move those methods elsewhere... say, to a utility class where one set of methods can be shared with both samples 1 and 3. Since you mentioned threading, typically this style makes it easier, not harder, to do multi-threading correctly.

One concrete example how this method style is better is that it's **composable**. This attribute allows me to re-write sample 3's Run() method like this and be confident of getting the same results:

```
Public Sub Run()
    TestVariable = Method3(Method2(Method1(TestVariable)))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  The fact that the code is in a form is irrelevant.  I have edited the code in the question.  Could you take another look? Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, final answer edit. Need to move on to actual assigned work now.

Comment: Thanks.  Finally, would you use sample 1 or sample 3 in your own apps? I realize that this depends to some extent on the problem domain.

Comment: 1 vs 3 have different behaviors. Which one I would depends **entirely** on which behavior I need. Neither is better than the other.